# Find and Replace text in the entire table using a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Usually I use manual find to replace text in a MySQL database using phpMyAdmin. I'm tired of it now, how can I run a query to find and replace a text with new text in the entire table in phpMyAdmin?

Example: find keyword `domain.example`, replace with `www.domain.example`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/639531/mysql-search-in-all-fields-from-every-table-from-a-database

Comment: You can do some thing like [this][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562457/search-for-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-a-mysql-database/10182498#10182498

Comment: [This](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB) will help you achieve what you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL string replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956993/mysql-string-replace)

Answer (score 669, accepted):

For a `single table` update

```
 UPDATE `table_name`
 SET `field_name` = replace(same_field_name, 'unwanted_text', 'wanted_text')
```

From `multiple tables`-

If you want to edit from all tables, best way is to take the `dump` and then `find/replace` and upload it back.

Comment: Worked for me when I dropped the single quotes

Comment: More on this: `If you want to edit from all tables, best way is to take the dump and then find/replace and upload it back.` Use sed on the dump for the find/replace: `sed "s:unwanted_text:wanted_text:g" dump.sql`

Comment: 1. Export to sql file 2. Find and replace 3. Import

Comment: Works great. As others have stated, sometimes I have to mess with the quotes to get it to work in phpMyAdmin. I used it to replace only the text "http:" with "https:" in a column containing full web addresses. The rest of the web addresses were untouched.

Answer (score 70):

The easiest way I have found is to dump the database to a text file, run a sed command to do the replace, and reload the database back into MySQL.

All commands below are bash on Linux.

Dump database to text file

```
mysqldump -u user -p databasename > ./db.sql
```

Run sed command to find/replace target string

```
sed -i 's/oldString/newString/g' ./db.sql
```

Reload the database into MySQL

```
mysql -u user -p databasename < ./db.sql
```

Easy peasy.

Comment: This works amazingly fast. I love this solution. I had to do some url replacements and instead of using slashes as my delimiters I used pipes instead (read this up http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html). Example:  `sed -i 's|http://olddomain.com|http://newdomain.com|g' ./db.sql`

Comment: It was so fast i thought it didn't work. But it did!
Also, you can just escape slashes like this: `\/\/domain.com`

Comment: Just a reminder that in OS X, the `sed -i` command may throw out `unterminated substitute pattern` error. You can use `sed -i '' -e 's/oldString/newString/g' ./db.sql` instead.

Comment: That's just great. I had one little backup, because we never know, just after the mysqldump : cp dl.sql db.sqlBACK

Answer (score 29):

Running an SQL query in phpMyAdmin to find and replace text in all WordPress blog posts, such as finding `mysite.example/wordpress` and replacing that with `mysite.example/news`
Table in this example is tj_posts

```
UPDATE `tj_posts`
SET `post_content` = replace(post_content, 'mysite.example/wordpress', 'mysite.example/news')
```

Comment: Thanks for the query. For my WordPress site the column name is `wp_posts` so the query looks ``UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_content` = replace(post_content, 'mysite.com/wordpress', 'mysite.com/news')``

Answer (score 28):

Put this in a php file and run it and it should do what you want it to do.

```
// Connect to your MySQL database.
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "db_username";
$password = "db_password";
$database = "db_name";

mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);

// The find and replace strings.
$find = "find_this_text";
$replace = "replace_with_this_text";

$loop = mysql_query("
    SELECT
        concat('UPDATE ',table_schema,'.',table_name, ' SET ',column_name, '=replace(',column_name,', ''{$find}'', ''{$replace}'');') AS s
    FROM
        information_schema.columns
    WHERE
        table_schema = '{$database}'")
or die ('Cant loop through dbfields: ' . mysql_error());

while ($query = mysql_fetch_assoc($loop))
{
        mysql_query($query['s']);
}
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, nice suggestion though - would have been sweet

Comment: Based on comment this is a simple solution for WordPress with mysqli:

`$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);`
`$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4');`
`$find = "old";`
`$replace = "new";`
`$query = "SELECT concat('UPDATE ',table_schema,'.',table_name, ' SET ',column_name, '=replace(',column_name,', ''{$find}'', ''{$replace}'');') AS s FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = '".DB_NAME."'";`
`$loop = $mysqli->query($query) or die ('Cant loop through dbfields: ' . $mysqli->error());`
`while ($query = $loop->fetch_assoc()) { $mysqli->query($query['s']); }`

Answer (score 17):

phpMyAdmin includes a neat find-and-replace tool.

Select the table, then hit **Search** > **Find and replace**

This query took about a minute and successfully replaced several thousand instances of `oldurl.ext` with the `newurl.ext` within Column `post_content`

[image: screenshot of the find-and-replace feature in phpMyAdmin]

Best thing about this method : You get to check every match before committing.

N.B. I am using phpMyAdmin 4.9.0.1

Comment: This is the only method I've tried which actually works!

Answer (score 15):

Another option is to generate the statements for each column in the database:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    'update ', table_name ,
    ' set ', column_name, ' = replace(', column_name,', ''www.oldDomain.example'', ''www.newDomain.example'');'
) AS statement
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'mySchema' AND table_name LIKE 'yourPrefix_%';
```

This should generate a list of update statements that you can then execute.

Comment: Slower than dumping, but for people that don't feel comfortable with the command line, this answer is creative and effective.

Comment: This is by far the best approach, if you have a lot of data and cannot dump/reload it.

Comment: Oh man this worked great! I will share my scripts based on this idea

Comment: This is an underrated solution. Totally worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

```
 UPDATE table SET field = replace(field, text_needs_to_be_replaced, text_required);
```

Like for example, if I want to replace all occurrences of John by Mark I will use below,

```
UPDATE student SET student_name = replace(student_name, 'John', 'Mark');
```

Answer (score 9):

If you are positive that none of the fields to be updated are serialized, the solutions above will work well.

However, if any of the fields that need updating contain serialized data, an SQL Query or a simple search/replace on a dump file, will break serialization (unless the replaced string has exactly the same number of characters as the searched string).

To be sure, a "serialized" field looks like this:

```
a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}
```

The number of characters in the relevant data is encoded as part of the data.
Serialization is a way to convert "objects" into a format easily stored in a database, or to easily transport object data between different languages.
Here is an explanation of [different methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11818086/5411817) used to serialize object data, and why you might want to do so, and here is a WordPress-centric post: [Serialized Data, What Does That Mean And Why is it so Important?](https://wp-staging.com/serialized-data-wordpress-important/) in plain language.

It would be amazing if MySQL had some built in tool to handle serialized data automatically, but it does not, and since there are different serialization formats, it would not even make sense for it to do so.

**wp-cli**
Some of the answers above seemed specific to WordPress databases, which serializes much of its data. WordPress offers a command line tool, [wp search-replace](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/), that *does* handle serialization.
A basic command would be:

```bash
    wp search-replace 'an-old-string' 'a-new-string' --dry-run
```

However, WordPress emphasizes that the [`guid` should never be changed](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/#important-guid-note), so it recommends skipping that column.
It also suggests that often times you'll want to skip the `wp_users` table.
Here's what that would look like:

`wp search-replace 'https://old-domain.example' 'https://shiney-new-domain.com' --skip-columns=guid --skip-tables=wp_users --dry-run`

Note: I added the `--dry-run` flag so a copy-paste won't automatically ruin anyone's database. After you're sure the script does what you want, run it again without that flag.

**Plugins**
If you are using WordPress, there are also many free and commercial plugins available that offer a gui interface to do the same, packaged with many additional features.

**Interconnect/it PHP script**
Interconnect/it offers a PHP script to handle serialized data: [Safe Search and Replace](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) tool. It was created for use on WordPress sites, but it looks like it can be used on any database serialized by PHP.
Many companies, including WordPress itself, recommends this tool. [Instructions](https://interconnectit.com/blog/2009/10/07/migrating-a-wordpresswpmubuddypress-website/) here, about 3/4 down the page.

Comment: I just wanted to add that I hadn't come across the wp-cli before but thanks to your post, I've managed to migrate my site and access it successfully affter replacing the old url strings.

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE  `MySQL_Table` 
SET  `MySQL_Table_Column` = REPLACE(`MySQL_Table_Column`, 'oldString', 'newString')
WHERE  `MySQL_Table_Column` LIKE 'oldString%';
```

Comment: Worth noting that this will only work where the oldString is at the start of the value, so "1oldString2" would not be replaced, but "oldString2" would - to replace all instances you'll need LIKE '%oldString%'  (note the additional %)

Answer (score 2):

I believe "swapnesh" answer to be the best ! Unfortunately I couldn't execute it in phpMyAdmin (4.5.0.2) who although illogical (and tried several things) it kept saying that a new statement was found and that no delimiter was found…

Thus I came with the following solution that might be usefull if you exeprience the same issue and have no other access to the database than PMA…

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` AS `toUpdate`,
(SELECT `ID`,REPLACE(`guid`,'http://old.tld','http://new.tld') AS `guid` 
 FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `guid` LIKE 'http://old.tld%') AS `updated`
SET `toUpdate`.`guid`=`updated`.`guid`
WHERE `toUpdate`.`ID`=`updated`.`ID`;
```

To test the expected result you may want to use :

```
SELECT `toUpdate`.`guid` AS `old guid`,`updated`.`guid` AS `new guid`
FROM `wp_posts` AS `toUpdate`,
(SELECT `ID`,REPLACE(`guid`,'http://old.tld','http://new.tld') AS `guid`
 FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `guid` LIKE 'http://old.tld%') AS `updated`
WHERE `toUpdate`.`ID`=`updated`.`ID`;
```

Answer (score 1):

the best you export it as sql file and open it with editor such as visual studio code and find and repalace your words.
i replace in 1 gig file sql in 1 minutes for 16 word that total is 14600 word.
its the best way.
and after replace it save and import it again.
do not forget compress it with zip for import.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of sentences with uppercase - lowercase letters,
 We can use BINARY REPACE

```
UPDATE `table_1`  SET  `field_1` =  BINARY REPLACE(`field_1`, 'find_string', 'replace_string')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to find and replace in Database

```sql
 UPDATE TABLE_NAME
 SET COLUMN = replace(COLUMN,'domain.example', 'www.domain.example')
```

`TABLE_NAME` => Change it with your table name

`COLUMN` => Change it to your column make sure it exists

Answer (score 0):

#### Generate change SQL queries (FAST)

`mysql -e "SELECT CONCAT( 'update ', table_name , ' set ', column_name, ' = replace(', column_name,', ''www.oldsite.example'', ''www.newsite.example'');' ) AS statement FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name LIKE 'wp_%'" -u root -p your_db_name_here > upgrade_script.sql`

#### Remove any garbage at the start of the file. I had some.

`nano upgrade_script.sql`

#### Run generated script with --force options to skip errors. (SLOW - grab a coffee if big DB)

`mysql -u root -p your_db_name_here --force < upgrade_script.sql`

Answer (score 0):

I have good luck with this query when doing a search and replace in phpmyadmin:

UPDATE `tableName` SET `fieldName1` = 'foo' WHERE `fieldName1` = 'bar';

Of course this only applies to one table at a time.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use regular expression

```
UPDATE `table` SET `field_name` =  REGEXP_REPLACE(`same_field_name`, 'unwanted_text', 'wanted_text')
```