# return rows where equals NONE in MySQL query

Tags: mysql

My data (tyreinfo) table is this:

```
width | ratio | rim
------+-------+----
35    | NONE  | 40
40    | NONE  | 90
22    | 22    | 70
```

when I tried mysql query

```
SELECT * from tyreinfo WHERE ratio=NONE
```

it gave me an error: Unknown column 'NONE' in 'where clause'. But this query works when I tried

```
SELECT * from tyreinfo WHERE ratio=22
```

I also tried:

```
SELECT * from tyreinfo WHERE ratio='NONE'
```

It gives me no results. What is the correct query?

Comment: post the `show create table tyreinfo` output please

Comment: What is the type of tyreinfo? Is it set as varchar or int?

Comment: @guido, it is: Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob do you mean the type of ratio? it is text

Comment: @Alex that does not look like a mysql error; are you using a gui?

Comment: @guido I am using phpmyadmin

Comment: SELECT * from tyreinfo WHERE ratio='NONE' is correct with a text column type and should give you the correct results. I suggest you create a simple sqlFiddle.

Comment: @mseifert Thanks mseifert, it is the right one. The reason I did not get the result was because it includes an ENTER in my data field. I have got over 300 rows in my data table, do you know how I can trim all the data in the table?

Comment: This should do it: read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839060/find-and-replace-text-in-all-table-using-mysql-query)

Answer (score 0):

to your last question:

```
UPDATE tyreinfo SET ratio='NONE' WHERE ratio like 'NONE%'
```

I guess it's what you mean - it will change ratio to 'NONE' in every row where ratio begins at 'NONE'.