# Remove whitespace in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following data (this is a slice of 4000 records):

```
    --------------------------------+
    | google_location_hours                                                                                   |
    +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | 11.30 AM - 5 AM,11.30 AM - 5 AM,11.30 AM - 5 AM,11.30 AM - 5 AM,11.30 AM - 5 AM,2 PM - 5 AM,4 PM - 5 AM |
    +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you notice, the data looks like this `11.30 AM - 5 AM`

I need to replace it with this `11.30AM-5AM`. This goes for every comma separated data in this record (and then applied on several thousand records).

Not quite sure how to handle this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find and Replace text in all table using mysql query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839060/find-and-replace-text-in-all-table-using-mysql-query)

Comment: @RyanVincent Absolutely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL's [`replace`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function seems to hit the mark:

```
SELECT REPLACE(google_location_hours, ' ', '')
FROM   mytable
```

EDIT:

If you wish to replace the actual data in the table, the same function could be used with an `update` statement:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET    google_location_hours = REPLACE(google_location_hours, ' ', '')
```

Comment: This looks like what I need however your doing a select and i need a straight replacement

Comment: @jkushner Gordon beat me to the comment - the same logic can be used with an `update` statement. See my edited answer.