# Wordpress: srcset gets HTTP instead of HTTPS in all posts

Tags: wordpress, image, https, srcset

In [Wordpress 4.4 images get automatically a `srcset` attribute](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/11/10/responsive-images-in-wordpress-4-4/). My problem with this was the following (I solved it while I was writing this question, see my answer below):

- in order to **transit everything to https**, I replaced all the `src="http://...` references in the [posts table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11839113/1326147) by `src="https://...` (I changed it later to `src="//...` for supporting both protocols);
- the images on all the posts get the correct URL in the `src` attribute;
- however in all the images that get the `srcset` attribute the URLs in it are always with `http://` references.

Why does this happen? Why these URLs don't get my newly updated `https://` beginnings?

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to change your WordPress Address (URL) to https then just put this code inside your active themes functions.php file

```
function codextent_ssl_srcset( $sources ) {
    foreach ( $sources as &$source ) {
        $source['url'] = set_url_scheme( $source['url'], 'https' );
    }
    return $sources;
}
add_filter( 'wp_calculate_image_srcset', 'codextent_ssl_srcset' );
```

** Also add this in top line of wp-config.php file.

```
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
```

Comment: This was the least invasive solution for me because I am using a lightsale bitnami deployment and the domain name is all handled by bitnomi functions.

Comment: i only add $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on'; and its working. thanks

Answer (score 4):

After searching for a while in the `wp-includes` folder, the `wp_calculate_image_srcset` method in the `media.php` file uses these 2 lines:

```
$image_baseurl = _wp_upload_dir_baseurl();
$image_baseurl = trailingslashit( $image_baseurl ) . $dirname;
```

And this `$image_baseurl` will actually form the new URL for the `srcset` attribute, i.e. even if the entire URL is in the `wp_posts`table and used in the `src` attribute, its beginning won't be used.

This means that if your base url in the `wp_options` table is still in `http://`, the images will get that protocol and won't show up by default by your browser when navigating in https.

For solving this, you just need to change the URLs inside the `option_value` in the `wp_options` table to `https://` or just `//` if you still want to support both protocols ([double slashed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646407/two-forward-slashes-in-a-url-src-href-attribute)). You can do this in a single query:

```
UPDATE `wp_options`
 SET `option_value` = replace(option_value, 'http://', '//')
 WHERE `option_name` IN ('siteurl', 'home')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the query leads to Wordpress being unable to set its cookies, so wp-admin breaks :(it attempts to set them on path //host.name/

Comment: @alamar a suggestion, if you may: once you have transferred all your content to http**s** and you are sure your public pages present all the images, you will not need the `//` any longer. At this time, you can run the same update where the replace string is `https://´. I no longer have the need to support both protocols and at that time this worked for me at least, but I believe that some side effects may take place... I did not mark this answer as accepted on purpose, so if you figure out how to solve both problems, I'll be glad to read it.

Comment: I have a similar problem, can you help? [How to convert srcset links from https to http?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/345569/64282)

Answer (score 4):

Change Following Setting in admin under Setting->General:

WordPress Address (URL) : https://yoursitename.com
Site Address (URL)      : https://yoursitename.com

And press [Save Changes] button. Finally refresh your page and your image will be displayed on your browser with correct srcset attribute.