# Mysql find replace with chars <, =, ", >

Tags: mysql, replace, find

I've read how to perform a [find-replace in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839060/find-and-replace-text-in-all-table-using-mysql-query),

```
UPDATE `table_name`
 SET `field_name` = replace(same_field_name, 'unwanted_text', 'wanted_text')
```

but i'm stuck with a particular string (my `unwanted_text`), that is

`<span style="font-size: 12pt;">`

In order to prevent any unwanted result, i'm testing my query just finding the previous string.

I've tried to escape double quotes with `\"` and even blank spaces with `\` but it doesn't work.

`<span\ style=\"font-size:\ 12pt;\">`

How should be `unwanted_text`?

Comment: Did you quote the whole text? `'<span style=\"font-size: 12pt;\">'`

Comment: Are the values *exactly* the same? Do you want to remove all tags, or only this specific one? What about the corresponding closing tag? Is that not in your column values?

Comment: Yes to both, but finally found the issue.

Thank you, i'm going to reply with the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Solved. It was Phpmyadmin through its search function converting: it was adding another `\`.

Through direct sql input everything works fine.