# find and replace values in a column

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

phpmyadmin

column name - `level`
current values - `lev1` `lev2` `lev3` `lev4`...
wanted values - `1` `2` `3` `4` ...

According to accepted and highly voted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839060/find-and-replace-text-in-the-entire-table-using-a-mysql-query), code should be like this:

```
UPDATE tmatria SET level = replace(level, 'lev', '');
```

But entering the above code inside phpmyadmin sql window I have a lot of errors.

What is the correct way to do this ?

Comment: What are the errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value have alway the same prefix  You can also use

```
UPDATE tmatria 
SET level = substr(level, 4, 100);
```

Comment: Please provide explanation to your answer.

Comment: @MilanGupta  .. is simple  do the fact the OP have problem  using the update with repalce .. i suggest an alternative  .. in this case having a fixed prefix a solution is set  the column level wth the right substr of the string....  (4,100) )   mean the substring starting form the forth character to 100 char (100 is an high value for take all the char) .. hope is clear ..and useful for you