# Search & replace 'http' to 'https' in database

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Using **phpmyadmin**, I want to run a query that will search my *entire* database for:

```
http://example.com
```

And replace with:

```
https://example.com
```

My SQL knowledge is limited, maybe something like:

```
UPDATE ?? = REPLACE(??, 'http://example.com', 'https://example.com');
```

The database is over 1gb, so what can I run that will *not* crash the server.

Update: Note that while there are other answers posted here on SO that deals with search and replace, they don't seem to cover the entire database.

Comment: UPDATE is for one table only, and you have to specify what column(s) to update.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find and Replace text in the entire table using a MySQL query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839060/find-and-replace-text-in-the-entire-table-using-a-mysql-query)

Comment: @jarlh What is the solution for searching the entire database instead of one table/column?

Comment: "Note that while there are other answers posted here on SO that deals with search and replace, they don't seem to cover the entire database." The duplicate thread I linked to covers that.

Comment: I would simply export the entire database - and then do the search and replace in sublime or any other text editor with SAR, and then reupload it.

Comment: The trick is to know where you store the url's. Database design issue!

Answer (score 52):

use REPLACE. and if there is a index on the field then the UPDATE can use them

```
UPDATE t
     set url = REPLACE(url, 'http:', 'https:')
     WHERE url LIKE '%http:%';
```

**only change example.com**

this will only find row with 'http://example.com'

```
UPDATE t
     set url = REPLACE(url, 'http:', 'https:')
     WHERE url LIKE '%http://example.com%';
```

or this will find all rows with http:// but only change only this http://example.com to https://example.com

```
UPDATE t
     set url = REPLACE(url, 'http://example.com', 'https://example.com')
     WHERE url LIKE '%http:%';
```

Comment: How can make it target `example.com` domains only? Will your code affect all tables? What does the `t` in `UPDATE t` stand for? Some clarification would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: i have add it in my answer

Comment: Will this replace the following terms `loremhttp://example.com/ipsum.html` or array entries like `array('hellohttp://example.com/go.html')`?

Comment: Very useful. I modified the latter part to this: `like '%http:%'`

Comment: examle code see here
https://domhtml.ru/wordpress_replase_http_https_db_mysql/

Comment: @Gjermund Dahl Why do we need the `like` key since REPLACE will do nothing if the string doesn't exist !

Answer (score 3):

**Warning, the answers given so far will mess up serialized data!**

For example, say your site stores serialized data in a row with the URL in it, like this:

```
a:1:{i:0;s:19:”http://example.com”;}
```

Notice that the value of this item has 19 characters, and is denoted by s:19 in the array.

If you replace content using a SQL query, the same row on your new environment would end up like this:

```
a:1:{i:0;s:19:”https://example.com”;}
```

But after this change, the value is now 20 characters long meaning s:19 is incorrect. This invalidates the array and the entire row.

So either you make sure your SQL statements deal with serialized data, or if you happen to be using WordPress then there are a few options to search using PHP so as to not break the serialized rows:

- The [Better Search Replace plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/) automatically handles serialized
  data
- The [Search and Replace plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/) offers an option which handles
  serialized data

*Taken and adapted from: https://wpengine.com/support/wordpress-serialized-data/*

Comment: -1 Because the OP asks how he can perform the action using phpmyadmin - not with a plug-in. 
Your warning is a valuable contribution -.much appreciated, but it is not an answer to the question.
Please add the appropriate SQL statement(s) to use in phpmyadmin and remove the links to the plug-ins. If I see an updated answer that fits the guidelines I will +1 the -1.

Comment: @TobiasBeuving I edited the answer to make it more on-topic, generically pointing to making sure that that SQL statements deal with serialized data. Regarding the WordPress plugins part, I prefixed it with "if you happen to be using WordPress", so now it can be see more like an extra advice.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `insert`:

```
update t
     set url = insert(url, 5, 0, 's')
     where url like 'http:%';
```

Comment: Could you kindly update your answer with explanation on your code? How can make it target `example.com` domains only? And what is the `update t` part?

Comment: `update t` is the syntax for updating a table; `t` is the table.  If you want to target `example.com`, then you include that in the `where` clause, probably as `where url like `'http://www.example.com/%'` or something similar.