# query to replace term in all tables of database

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to search for `http://example.com` and replace with `https://example.com`.

I know I can target a specific table and column with this approach:

```
UPDATE table_name SET post_content = REPLACE(column_name, 'http://example.com', 'https://example.com');
```

But how do I run a query which targets all tables/columns: the entire database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search & replace 'http' to 'https' in database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42857921/search-replace-http-to-https-in-database)

Answer (score 0):

Do a DB dump and open it as a text file. Find and replace. Save and then re-import.

As far as I know, I don't think you can use REPLACE on all tables in one query.

Answer (score 0):

There a two ways to do it. The first is to create SQL UPDATE via the information_schema and execute it as prepared statement. this is much work.

you must look at each column if you can do a replace, so you must ignore INTS and ENUMs etc.

The second way is not a real SQL change, but it works: Generate a full SQL-Dump from your database and make the changes in this file via editor or via commandline with AWK or SED. After this you can import the changed file