# Remove tags &nbsp; on Table HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, yii2

I made print layout with HTML.
When I retrieve data from database, somehow the string results in the tags `&nbsp;` as shown in the following picture:

[image]

And on console when a try to `print_r()`, the result as shown in the following picture:

[image]

So, how the way to remove tag `&nbsp;` on `td`. I've tried using `trim()` and `str_replace()`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You want a `php` solution or a `Javascript` one?

Comment: php or mysql_query @Shidersz

Comment: Please, replace the `Javascript` tag by `MySQL` then and add the relevant part of your code. Have you tried `$new_str = str_replace("&nbsp;", '', $str);`?

Comment: I have use str_replace, but doesn't work. Is possible because I used it when rendering the layout ?

Comment: Will be hard to tell if you don't include an example of how you are getting your data from the database and the php code you are trying to use for replace the `&nbsp;` elements

Comment: Problem solved @Shidersz, before use str_replace, I use htmlentities to make &nbsp; be string. Thanks thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're doing `str_replace('&nbsp;', '', $string)` before encoding output. So you need to replace decoded `&nbsp;`:

```
str_replace(html_entity_decode('&nbsp;'), '', $string);
```

Or

```
str_replace("\xc2\xa0", '', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("table:td").each(function(index) {
   $(this).text($(this).text().replace("&nbsp;", ""));
});
```

Alternative

```
$.each($("body").find("table"), function() {
     this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.split("&nbsp;").join("");
});
```

Comment: how with php or mysql_query Sir ? because javascript doesn't work if i export to pdf

Answer (score 0):

use `innerHTML` to get the raw html markup and then replace all `&nbsp;` with empty string.

```js
const td = document.querySelector('td');

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    const text = td.innerHTML;
    console.log('Before: ', text);
    td.textContent = text.replace(/&nbsp;/gi, '');
    console.log('After: ', td.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem &nbsp;Inpsum &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button>Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: how with php or mysql_query Sir ? because javascript doesn't work if i export to pdf

Comment: Might be this answer would help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839060/find-and-replace-text-in-the-entire-table-using-a-mysql-query