# Remove all IFRAMES

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I would like to remove all iframes and it's content from my website. Every single one.

[Iframes Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/224RG.png)

I have over 1,500 in the database. Is there a quick method to remove each iframe and it's content without having to manually delete each one?

My website is running Wordpress.

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You can  use find and replace query of mysqli to replace iframe data with NULL. I can see in your screenshot that the iframe data is same so its easy to remove them by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839060/find-and-replace-text-in-the-entire-table-using-a-mysql-query

P.S: Make sure to backup your mysqli in case of any issue.

Comment: Sorry for the extremely long delay in replying to you. Thank you for your input, however! I did find an easy solution to this, I used Notepad++ and a simple find & replace using: `<iframe.*<\/iframe>`. This removed all iframes within the respective table.