# How to change file extension in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql

I have formatted all my PNG file to WebP file on my server. I need to update my database on phpMyAdmin:

```
images.png --> images.webp
images1.png --> images1.webp
images2.png --> images2.webp
```

```sql
UPDATE `gallery` SET `image_name` = '16240154071618319441c1.webp' WHERE `gallery`.`id` = 1;` ;
```

I have 5000 records to do.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find and Replace text in the entire table using a MySQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839060/find-and-replace-text-in-the-entire-table-using-a-mysql-query)

Comment: interesting aside: webp is a very niche format that hasn't got that much traction and I think may actually be Google proprietary, whereas PNG is well established and integrated.

Answer (score 0):

Use [replace](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) , but I suggest specifying only the last part of the string.

```
UPDATE `gallery` 
SET `image_name` = replace(image_name,(right(image_name,4)),'.webp');
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/Iu4InO0r

The string ending with `.png` will be converted to `.webp`